# better way to pass data to print in python

Tags: python

I was going through http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/02 and found this:

```
>>> print 'number is ' + str(3)
number is 3
>>> print 'number is %s' % (3)
number is 3
>>> print 'number is %(number)s' % dict(number=3)
number is 3
```

It has been given that `The last notation is more explicit and less error prone, and is to be preferred.`

I am wondering what is the advantage of using the last notation.. will it not have a performance overhead?

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. If your application is slow, I'm quite that sure dictionary substitution won't be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> print 'number is ' + str(3)
number is 3
```

This is definitely the worst solution and might cause you problems if you do the beginner mistake `"Value of obj: " + obj` where `obj` is not a string or unicode object. For many concatenations, it's not readable at all - it's similar to something like `echo "<p>Hello ".$username."!</p>";` in PHP (this can get arbitrarily ugly).

---

> > > print 'number is %s' % (3)
> > >           number is 3

Now that is much better. Instead of a hard-to-read concatenation, you see the output format immediately. Coming back to the beginner mistake of outputting values, you can do `print "Value of obj: %r" % obj`, for example. I personally prefer this in most cases. But note that you cannot use it in gettext-translated strings if you have multiple format specifiers because the order might change in other languages.

As you forgot to mention it here, you can also use the new string formatting method which is similar:

```
>>> "number is {0}".format(3)
'number is 3'
```

---

Next, dict lookup:

```
>>> print 'number is %(number)s' % dict(number=3)
number is 3
```

As said before, gettext-translated strings might change the order of positional format specifiers, so this option is the best when working with translations. The performance drop should be negligible - if your program is not all about formatting strings.

As with the positional formatting, you can also do it in the new style:

```
>>> "number is {number}".format(number=3)
'number is 3'
```

---

It's hard to tell which one to take. I recommend you to use positional arguments with the `%` notation for simple strings and dict lookup formatting for translated strings.

Comment: where is this `>>> "number is {number}".format(number=3)` sort of formating is good?

Comment: @aaronasterling: Thanks for the edit :D. Of course I meant it's negligible.

Comment: @Idlecool: Well, it's the "new style" formatting introduced in a later Python version (`%` is the "old style"). Just choose the one you prefer most. I haven't yet seen a case in which new style formatting has an advantage.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few differences.

1. **First to me is cumbersome**, if more than one variable is involved. I can not speak of performance penalty on that. See additional arguments below.
2. The **second example is positional dependent** and it can be easy to change position causing errors.  It also does not tell you anything about the variables.
3. **The third example, the position of variables is not important. You use a dictionary**. This makes it elegant as it does not rely on positional structuring of variables.

See the example below:

```
>>> print 'number is %s %s' % (3,4)
number is 3 4
>>> print 'number is %s %s' % (4,3)
number is 4 3
>>> print 'number is %(number)s %(two)s' % dict(number=3, two=4)
number is 3 4
>>> print 'number is %(number)s %(two)s' % dict(two=4, number=3)
number is 3 4
>>>
```

Also another part of discussion on this

**"+" is the string concatenation operator.**

**"%" is string formatting.**

In this trivial case, string formatting accomplishes the same result as concatenation. Unlike string formatting, string concatenation only works when everything is already a string. So if you miss to convert your variables to string, concatenation will cause error.

[Edit: My answer was biased towards templating since the question came from web2py where templates are so commonly involved]

**As Ryan says below, the concatenation is faster than formatting.**

Suggestion is

1. **Use the first form** - concatenation, if you are concatenating just two strings
2. **Use the second form**, if there are few variables. You can invariably see the positions and deal with them
3. **Use the third form** when you are doing templating i.e. formatting a large piece of string with variable data. The dictionary form helps in providing meaning to variables inside the large piece of text.

Comment: Using the concatenation operator is _much much_ faster than the formating operator which is itself significantly slower than the `.format` method. I would recommend using concatenation in places like inner loops when reasonable to do so.

Comment: @aaronasterling: If you need performance, the worst thing you could do is using + operator, and invoking an O(n**2) behavior; if you need performance, use str.join() instead.

Comment: @Lie Ryan, good point for more than one concatenation. I generally don't ever use it for more than that so wasn't thinking about more than two strings.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: @aaronasterling: I agree concatenation is faster and for simple single string concatenation that is best way to do it. I wish, I had added that in my answer. I assumed that this question was with respect to formatting with multiple values. In such situation, I prefer the third option. Rayan has already added a gamut of places where you want to do that. I also do not agree that it is cumbersome, violates DRY and is error prone.

Comment: @Idlecool: It would be good to make a comment on why you switched to accept a different answer, when that answer seems to be not very different from mine and is answered and edited much after I have provided the same information more or less.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering what is the advantage
>   of using the last notation..

Hm, as you said, the last notation is really more **explicit** and actually is less error prone.

> will it not have a performance
>   overhead?

It will have little performance overhead, but it's minor if compared with data fetching from DB or network connections.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: See my answer above. I guess it is not about performance but about other errors that can be induced if we rely on the positions of variables for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

**It's a bad, unjustified piece of advice.**

The third method is *cumbersome, violates DRY, and error prone*, except if:

1. You are writing a framework which don't have control over the format string. For example, `logging` module, `web2py`, or `gettext`.
2. The format string is extremely long.
3. The format string is read from a file from a config file.

The problem with the third method should be obvious when you consider that `foo` appears three times in this code: `"%(foo)s" % dict(foo=foo)`. This is error prone. Most programs should not use the third method, unless they know they need to.

The second method is the simplest method, and is what you generally use in most programs. It is best used when the format string is immediate, e.g. `'values: %s %s %s' % (a, b, c)` instead of taken from a variable, e.g. `fmt % (a, b, c)`.

The first concatenation is almost never useful, except perhaps if you're building list by loops:

```
s = ''
for x in l:
    s += str(x)
```

however, in that case, it's generally better and faster to use str.join():

```
s = ''.join(str(x) for x in l)
```